# Is Pi - π a palindrome?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi, palindrome

Till yesterday, I knew π as an irrational number. But I accidentally saw a blog, which says that**π is a palindrome**, **ending in the decimals 51413**. Is **Pi** is **a palindrome**, not an irrational number? Whether it is irrational or not, can you pls *prove* in **simple method**?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the post? How could $\pi$ be a palindrome if it has no 'last digit' to bring to the front when you 'flip' it?

Comment: It would be a mildly interesting question whether any (nontrivial) _prefix_ of the decimal expansion of $\pi$ is a palindrome. I expect the answer is _probably_ no, but it is almost certainly out of our present ability to _prove_ that it is no.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Mathematica shows that no prefixes less than $10,000$ are palindromic, apart from the trivial $1,4,1$ if you only count fractional digits.

Comment: It is not trivial to prove that $\pi$ is irrational, perhaps the easiest method is the continued fraction of the tangens-function which was used by Lambert. After this proof it still took very long until it was proven that $\pi$ is in fact transcendental by Lindemann.

Comment: @Dando18 Then it is almost certain that no such palindrome exists (Note that "$141$" does not count because the $3$ before the decimal point is missing)

Comment: @Peter hence the "only fractional digits" qualifier.

Comment: I once read the (false) claim that the probability that eventually a palindrome beginning with the first digits will occur with probability $1$. The fallacy is that we do not have an event with constant probability (which would occur eventually with probability $1$), but it is getting less and less probable that the desired palindrome will occur. But I agree Henning that a proof will be completely out of reach that there is none.

Comment: But a last digit of $\pi$ definitely does not exist, as already mentioned. It might be interesting that some people do not want to accept that $\pi$ is irrational and argue that every approximation one can use for the calculation of $\pi$ must be rational. Of course, this is not true because no (rational) approximation of $\pi$ IS $\pi$, it is only an approximation.

Comment: This week I debated with my kids the question of whether there any long palindromes in prefixes of pi. It seems very unlikely to me, since although we have an infinite series to sample from, each additional digit makes it ten times less likely we will find one.  On the other hand it’s a little easier if you work with a smaller base. In base 2 we find 11 but after the decimal the palindrome is lost. The longest we could find was in base e: 10.101.  I suspect that’s the longest we can find but maybe you could strategically choose a base that maximizes the length.

Comment: Sorry, that should be 1.0101 but it's too late for me to edit. :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not let that confuse you. You were right, $\pi$ is an irrational number with an infinite number of decimals, which means that it never ends. Maybe the guy in the blog truncated the decimals at some point or something, but saying that pi ends with anything is just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, $\pi$ is not a palindrome. It is irrational. Its decimal expansion continues forever and so it has no last digits.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. For more information on that I recommend this article: [The Last Digit of Pi](http://www.dancohen.org/2010/03/08/the-last-digit-of-pi/)